# How do I clean duplicate data in cells in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame where the column gender has duplicates within the cells, here is an example:

```
1. Male
2. Female, female
3. Female, female , Female, female
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert values to lowercase, then split, convert to `set`s and join back if necessary:

```
df['new'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x.lower().split(', '))))
print (df)
                                col     new
1.0                            Male    male
2.0                  Female, female  female
3.0  Female, female, Female, female  female
```

Solution for remove rows with rows not contains `,` - it means multiple values per cells:

```
print (df)
                              col
1.0                          Male
2.0                Female, female
3.0  Female, male, Female, female

df['new'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: '&'.join(set(x.lower().split(', '))))
print (df)
                              col          new
1.0                          Male         male
2.0                Female, female       female
3.0  Female, male, Female, female  female&male

df = df[df['new'].str.count('&') == 0]
print (df)
                col     new
1.0            Male    male
2.0  Female, female  female
```

Comment: I have just realized after running the above  code there're cells I'm getting `female,male`. Should I drop the rows or how should I go about it ?

Comment: @mickeywise - it means there are data like `Female, male , Female, female` in one cell. So you need remove this rows with this cells?

Comment: Will my analysis be bias because there'll be important information dropped from the rows.

Comment: @mickeywise - So need only first value before first `, ` ? Then use `df['new'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: x.split(', ')[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

you just keep the first split:

```
df['gender'] = df['gender'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[0])
```

for the case Male and Female inside same cell, its your choice, or you drop the row, or you decide the first Gender is ok (my solution) or you set another value to identify later. but its not your first demand

Comment: i dont know if your analysis will be biased, thats depends if the fact to drop the row is important or not for you. in anyways there is an error if you have both Female and Male, so you drop or you can isolate and fix later